# Pass Javascript function as Functional Interface type to Java method with Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I'm trying to figure out how to pass my Javascript function to my Java method so that I can call it at runtime.

I have the following Java Method Signature:

```
public static void createBlock(String domain, String name, String eventType, EventFunction eventHandler)
```

I am calling this from Javascript like this:

```
function main() {
    BlockManager.createBlock('sarah-egg', 'enderBlock', 'breakBlock', func);
}

function func (event) { 
    event.world.createExplosion(null, event.pos.getX(), event.pos.getY(), event.pos.getZ, 10, true); 
}
```

And I have made my Java Functional Interface, EventFunction, like this:

```
package com.learntomod.event;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface EventFunction<T> {
    void fun(T t);
}
```

When I run it, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot cast jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.ScriptFunctionImpl to com.learntomod.event.EventFunction
```

I tried changing EventFunction to Runnable and getting rid of the parameter, and it worked.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how functional interfaces work. They are no function references. If I understand https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html right you'd pass an `Invocable` to your Java method.

Comment: I have also tried passing an invocable instead of doing it this way - and that didn't work either.

My understanding is that both "should" work and the way I'm trying to do it is the way that people recommend with Java 8? But I'm not sure. 

I will re-read that doc and try it again though! :) Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a full, yet concise, reproducing example?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're trying to do what's described under [ Lambdas, SAM types and Script functions](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions): Implement the Java `EventFunction` interface in JavaScript as `function func(event)`. That's possible (compare http://ideone.com/amHsPp ) but I think you'll have to get rid of the generic `<T>`.

Comment: @Tunaki - my co-dev is working on a reproducing example now

Comment: Ok we did a basic example and it works in it's own file, but when I integrate it into my class it goes wonky again.

Full disclosure -> this is integrating into Forge for Minecraft Modding (doing some tricky things with a JS interface online) so maybe it has something to do with how Forge is handling the classes...looking into it now.

Answer (score 2):

OK - so it turns out that Forge might have been the culprit all along.

Forge does some wonky things with changing the class loader, and so Java might have just not auto-changed my JS function to my EventFunction Functional Interface type (or something like that).

In any case - I found a "solution" - I used https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html - which is a part of Java Util, and since Runnable worked, we decided to try Function (which takes in a parameter) and...it worked!

Now my custom blocks will explode when you break them ;)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IJVeC48z6I&feature=youtu.be

Thanks for your help guys!